# How to build pandas dataframe from multi-loop process that appends rows and columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to build a dataframe from data gathered from a crontab file. I am unsure how exactly to take the pieces and compile them into a dataframe.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from crontab import CronTab
import re

system_cron=CronTab()
user_cron=CronTab(user=True)
user_cron

#create and clean list of bash files

line=0
listJobs=[]
for job in user_cron:
    match = re.search('.sh', str(user_cron[line]))
    if match:
        pos=str(user_cron[line]).find('.sh')+3
        start=(str(user_cron[line])[::-1]).find(' ', 0)
        print(str(user_cron[line])[-start:pos])
        listJobs.append(str(user_cron[line])[-start:pos])
    line = line+1
listJobs = list(set(listJobs))
listJobs.remove("keybash.sh")

# listJobs is now a list of .sh files including their paths

# loop through the .sh files to pull the python notebooks

for job in listJobs:
    with(open(job, 'r')) as file:
        text=file.read()
        text = text.splitlines() 
    print(job)
    print(text)
type(text)

listFiles=[]
line=0
for file in text:
    match = re.search('ipynb', str(text[line]))
    if match:
        pos=str(text[line]).find('ipynb')+5
        start=(str(text[line])[::-1]).find(' ', 0)
        print(str(text[line])[-start:pos])
        listFiles.append(str(text[line])[-start:pos])
    line=line+1
listFiles
```

So now I have two lists with a different amount of rows, and not sure how to join them to get something like this:

[image]

I'm wondering if I should have used a dictionary or converted to a dataframe and then looped through that?  What would be the most efficient way to alter what I have code wise to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

```py
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['key'])
for i in range(10):
    df.loc[i] = i
15.8 ms ± 204 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
df = pd.DataFrame() 
for i in range(10):
    df = df.append({'key': i}, ignore_index=True)
14.7 ms ± 849 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
data = []
for i in range(10):
    data.append({'key': i})
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
668 µs ± 14.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```